# How to display multiple attributes in a single table view? Swift

Tags: swift

I want to display three different entitys from core data on a table view. I can do this with one entity and tried to carry that logic over to displaying three on the same table view. I used the same entity in the code below to test this. I am getting blank sections in my table view. I must have the cellForRowAt method wrong? Here is my code.

```
        var word: [NSManagedObject] = []
        let sections = ["Custom Library", "Mastered Words", "Library"]

        var array = [
              [NSManagedObject](),
              [NSManagedObject](),
              [NSManagedObject]()
              ]


        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")

        array = [
             word,
             word,
             word
            ]}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array[section].count
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section]

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let customWord = array[indexPath.row][indexPath.section]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = customWord.value(forKeyPath: "title") as? String
            return cell
```

Comment: I would be easier if you added the implementation of `numberOfSections:` and `numberOfRows(inSection:)` too, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, your `array` property is an array of empty arrays as `word` is an empty array itself.  If you're using `array` to determine the number of rows in each section based on the array at that section index, then you're going to get 0 rows for each section.

Comment: I do have three words saved to core data and are able to display them on a table view with a single section.

Comment: In the code you've shown, you're not pulling the words from core data anywhere.

Comment: The fetch request lives in this method: 
`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
      return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Data")

    do {
      word = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  }`

Comment: You should think about using NSFetchedResultsController to manage your table data for you.  It's more setup, but it takes care of so many things for you like add/removing cells.  But back to your original question, are your entities all subclassing the same parent class?

Comment: Also, after your fetch do you ever call `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: Yes, and yes I am reloading the data.

Comment: Have you verified your fetchRequest is getting data?